# Optional job parameter in AWS Glue?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

How can I implement an optional parameter to an AWS Glue Job?

I have created a job that currently have a string parameter (an ISO 8601 date string) as an input that is used in the ETL job. I would like to make this parameter optional, so that the job use a default value if it is not provided (e.g. using [datetime.now](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.now) and [datetime.isoformat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.isoformat)in my case). I have tried using [getResolvedOptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-get-resolved-options.html):

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['ISO_8601_STRING'])
```

However, when I am not passing an `--ISO_8601_STRING` job parameter I see the following error:

> awsglue.utils.GlueArgumentError: argument --ISO_8601_STRING is required

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Porting [Yuriy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52272137/303598) to Python solved my problem:

```
if ('--{}'.format('ISO_8601_STRING') in sys.argv):
    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['ISO_8601_STRING'])
else:
    args = {'ISO_8601_STRING': datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()}
```

Answer (score 21):

[matsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303598/matsev) and [Yuriy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52272137/303598) solutions is fine if you have only one field which is optional.

I wrote a wrapper function for python that is more generic and handle different corner cases (mandatory fields and/or optional fields with values).

```
import sys    
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

def get_glue_args(mandatory_fields, default_optional_args):
    """
    This is a wrapper of the glue function getResolvedOptions to take care of the following case :
    * Handling optional arguments and/or mandatory arguments
    * Optional arguments with default value
    NOTE: 
        * DO NOT USE '-' while defining args as the getResolvedOptions with replace them with '_'
        * All fields would be return as a string type with getResolvedOptions

    Arguments:
        mandatory_fields {list} -- list of mandatory fields for the job
        default_optional_args {dict} -- dict for optional fields with their default value

    Returns:
        dict -- given args with default value of optional args not filled
    """
    # The glue args are available in sys.argv with an extra '--'
    given_optional_fields_key = list(set([i[2:] for i in sys.argv]).intersection([i for i in default_optional_args]))

    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,
                            mandatory_fields+given_optional_fields_key)

    # Overwrite default value if optional args are provided
    default_optional_args.update(args)

    return default_optional_args
```

Usage :

```
# Defining mandatory/optional args
mandatory_fields = ['my_mandatory_field_1','my_mandatory_field_2']
default_optional_args = {'optional_field_1':'myvalue1', 'optional_field_2':'myvalue2'}
# Retrieve args
args = get_glue_args(mandatory_fields, default_optional_args)
# Access element as dict with args[‘key’]
```

Comment: Thanks for your wrapper function, @mehdio. I found that when I supplied optional args to the job with a value in the form `OPTION_ARG=value`, the `value` was ignored in preference for the value supplied in `default_optional_args` dictionary.  I tweaked you wrapper as follows:
   
`supplied = set([i[2:].split('=')[0] for i in sys.argv])`
`given_optional_fields_key = list((supplied).intersection([i for i in default_optional_args]))`

Comment: The intersection is basically just the set of arguments passed from outside overriding the defaults. I would suggest to rename **given_optional_fields_key** to something like **overrided_optional_fields_key**

Answer (score 8):

There is a workaround to have optional parameters. The idea is to examine arguments before resolving them (Scala):

```
val argName = 'ISO_8601_STRING'
var argValue = null
if (sysArgs.contains(s"--$argName"))
   argValue = GlueArgParser.getResolvedOptions(sysArgs, Array(argName))(argName)
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a way to have optional parameters, but you can specify default parameters on the job itself, and then if you don't pass that parameter when you run the job, your job will receive the default value (note that the default value can't be blank).

Answer (score 4):

Wrapping [matsev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52298107/2863603) in a function:

```
def get_glue_env_var(key, default="none"):
    if f'--{key}' in sys.argv:
        return getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, [key])[key]
    else:
        return default
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create a Step Function that starts the same Glue job with different parameters. The state machine starts with a Choice state and uses different number of inputs depending on which is present.

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    taskMachine:
      role:
        Fn::GetAtt: [ TaskExecutor, Arn ]
      name: ${self:service}-${opt:stage}
      definition:
        StartAt: DefaultOrNot
        States:

          DefaultOrNot:
            Type: Choice
            Choices:
              - Variable: "$.optional_input"
                IsPresent: false
                Next: DefaultTask
              - Variable: "$. optional_input"
                IsPresent: true
                Next: OptionalTask

          OptionalTask:
            Type: Task
            Resource:  "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.task0"
            Parameters:
              JobName: ${self:service}-${opt:stage}
              Arguments:
                '--log_group.$': "$.specs.log_group"
                '--log_stream.$': "$.specs.log_stream"
                '--optional_input.$': "$. optional_input"

            Catch:
              - ErrorEquals: [ 'States.TaskFailed' ]
                ResultPath: "$.errorInfo"
                Next: TaskFailed
            Next: ExitExecution


          DefaultTask:
            Type: Task
            Resource:  "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync"
            Parameters:
              JobName: ${self:service}-${opt:stage}
              Arguments:
                '--log_group.$': "$.specs.log_group"
                '--log_stream.$': "$.specs.log_stream"


            Catch:
              - ErrorEquals: [ 'States.TaskFailed' ]
                ResultPath: "$.errorInfo"
                Next: TaskFailed
            Next: ExitExecution

          TaskFailed:
            Type: Fail
            Error: "Failure"

          ExitExecution:
            Type: Pass
            End: True
```

Answer (score 0):

An AWS Glue job expects all the parameters, optional parameter is not an option currently.

Solution which I tried to have optional parameters, pass parameters as a JSON.

```
 --glue_params = {"var1":"value1", "var2":"value2", "optional_var1":"value3", "optional_var2": null}
```

In your code, handle the parameters accordingly

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,['JOB_NAME','glue_params'])
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using the interface, you must provide your parameter names starting with "--" like "--TABLE_NAME", rather than "TABLE_NAME", then you can use them like the following (python) code:

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'TABLE_NAME'])
table_name = args['TABLE_NAME']
```